# Hide/Safe javascript which will be imported from foreign sites from trackers

Tags: javascript, data-protection, user-tracking

In germany we have a service which is called "wahl-o-mat" or in english it may be called "elect-o-mat".
It's a service where citizens can answer simple opinion based question with "I agree", "I don't agree" or "neutral".
For example:
Should bavaria get a third national park.
The answers will be compared with answers from political parties. In the end it shall help with making a decision which party I want to vote.
While this is a nice way to make people think about political topics, the answers are somehow sensible.

And here is the problem: To expand the publicity they partnered with other companies which included the script in their pages. While the original provider doesn't use any trackers the partners did/do.
For example they use "heatmap" which can track the clicks on a page so it was possible to track the answers. [(german) source](https://www.golem.de/news/landtagswahlen-in-bayern-und-hessen-tracker-im-wahl-o-mat-der-bpb-medienpartner-1810-137096.html)

I wondered if there would have been a way to prevent this technically on a "don't trust anyone" base without a solution by contract ("you must not [...]")?
**Edit:**
According to the first comment I want to expand my question:
When there is such a simple solution. What's the benefit of not using it?

Comment: Yes using iframes. `<iframe src="http://machtmit.ga" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could embed an `<iframe />` into the partners site, through that the partner cannot access the content of the iframe. It could however still track where the user clicks inside the iframe. But one could prevent that easily by shuffling the answers, so that the tracker cannot relate a certain click location to an answer.

```
  <iframe src="https://www.wahl-o-mat.de" />
```

> What's the benefit of not using it?

You get tracking and customization.

Comment: This and if you can change on every reload the elements classes/id it will be even harder, but they can always track everything if they really want to, unfortunately there is no way to completely prevent it.